# Excel 2013 SUMIFS with multiple criteria one being data filter

Tags: excel

I need to sum data based on 3+ criteria one being the month.
"Usage" tab contains entries for`A=Date C=department, D=fuel E=Gallons`

Im trying to generate a monthly report where the following is true
`fuel=diesel`, `dept=public works`, `month=B2` (B2 is a month by number drop list, problem still exist if I substitute 1, 2, 3, etc.)

I can get the below formula to work until I add the date field, either I get `#NAME?`, or an error regarding my formula. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

`=SUM(IFS(Usage!$E:$E,(Usage!$D:$D),"Diesel",(Usage!$C:$C),"Public Works",MONTH(Usage!A:A),B2))`

Thanks
Vona

Answer (score 0):

If B2 contains =MONTH(A2) (copied down), please try:

```
=SUMIFS(Usage!E:E,Usage!D:D,"Diesel",Usage!C:C,"Public Works",Usage!B:B,X2)
```

Note no parenthesis in the middle of SUMIFS. X2 (or to suit) contains the month number of your choice (so may not work across years).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Im confused by the last criteria Usage!B:B,X2... what is X2? B2 is a drop list with numbers 1-12. Do I need to adjust what B2 contains?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found that provided the correct answer.  Thanks to all who made helped, your suggestions pointed me in the right direction!

=SUMPRODUCT((Usage!D2:D6="Diesel")*1,(Usage!C2:C6="Public Works")*1,(MONTH(Usage!A2:A6)=B2)*1,(YEAR(Usage!A2:A6)=C2)*1, Usage!E2:E6)